# Diagnosing Hangs in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, freeze

I recently got a new desktop PC with Windows 10 Pro x64, and for some reason it hangs about once every 24 hours (randomly, not at a specific time). The only way I could unhang it was restart the computer. I don't get a BSOD or any other diagnostic information I know of; in the event viewer it only lists problems that happen at startup, but nothing before that. The strangest thing to me is that it's as if some aspects of the PC work overall, like turning the monitor on and off shows the correct picture indefinitely, which means that it's probably not a graphics card problem, etc. Initially I thought it might just be a USB problem (keyboard + mouse stop working), but tried setting an alarm clock on the PC and it didn't activate, so it's probably not that.

Note that this has nothing to do with system load, so far it has never actually happened when the system was under load, in fact 3 out of the 4 times it happened, the system was idle (I was AFK).

I'd really just like to know how to diagnose such problems in Windows 10. In previous versions of Windows I'd always get either a BSOD or a graphics hang in such "unrecoverable" situations.

Specs:

- OS: Windows 10  Pro x64
- Processor: Intel Core i7-6700K
- Motherboard: ASUS Z170 Pro Gaming
- Graphics: Gigabyte GeForce GTX 970
- RAM: Corsair 2666 Mhz 16GB
- PSU: Corsair RM750 (Gold)

**Update:** I ran a memtest, reinstalled Windows, checked all hard drive, updated all drivers, and many other small things recommended in various forums, to no avail. So as a last resort I updated BIOS, and lo and behold, the freezes subsided considerably! My PC is on 24/7 and I've had just one freeze in the past month or so. Turns out ASUS weren't kidding when they wrote "stability improvements" in the change log. This motherboard luckily has a backup BIOS so that flashing it won't destroy it if the power goes out or something, but from my experience in general, updating BIOS should only be done as a last resort.

Still, the question remains open for anyone else interested: was it possible to figure out that BIOS was the problem through some kind of test? Because if, say, a technician wants to fix such a problem for a customer, they don't have tens of hours to spend randomly trying all kinds of solutions like I did.

Comment: Update drivers, special focus on LAN, audio, graphics. They might be causing problems

Comment: press CAPS LOCK key during the freeze. Does the light on the keyboard toggle? If yes, it is a software hang. If the light doesn't toggle, you have a hardware issue.

Comment: I updated all of the drivers, and the "lock" buttons don't toggle. How can I diagnose the hardware issue if there's no BSOD?

Comment: do a memory test with memtest86+, also make sure the RAm timings are fine. Also Corsair RAM can causes issues with ASUS boards.

Comment: I did a memory test and didn't get any errors. If indeed it's an inherent problem between Corsair and ASUS hardware, can I diagnose it before I shell out the cash for new RAM?